# Positioning of SVG text

Tags: xml, svg

I need to position and animate SVG text as follows. The start position is (the pipe character represents x=0):

```
.................|..................
      SOME_TEXT_1 
SOME_OTHER_TEXT_2
```

and the end position is:

```
.................|..................
                  SOME_TEXT_1 
                  SOME_OTHER_TEXT_2
```

To do this, I believe I need to know the size at runtime of the of the text and do something like:

```
    <animateMotion path="M 0 0 L SOME_TEXT_1_LENGTH 0" begin="0s" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
    <text x="0 - SOME_TEXT_1_LENGTH" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="36" fill="#ffffff">SOME_TEXT_1</text>
```

Is something like this possible (specifically, I'm referring to my usage of SOME_TEXT_1_LENGTH which isn't valid SVG but mathematically is what I would need)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already use text-anchor="end" for the first state, and text-anchor="start" for the end state? Animating text-anchor will give you a discrete transition, and you wouldn't even need to change the x position if I understood your example correctly.

However, if you don't want a discrete animation, then one way is to figure out the text length at runtime as you suggested, you can e.g use the method [getComputedTextLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength) on the text element in question to get the length of the text.

Comment: Thanks Erik! This definitely seems like the right answer although when I implemented it, the text is just switching to the new position halfway through the animation instead of smoothly animation from "end" to "start". I believe this is a bug in my SVG viewer though.

Comment: In case you're curious, here's my implementation: <text x="50"  y="50" width="400" fill="blue" text-anchor="start"><animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="text-anchor" begin="1s" dur="10s" from="start" to="end" fill="freeze" />Hello</text>

Comment: The "switching to the new position halfway" is what I described as "discrete animation" (step-wise). I think SVG viewers could be smarter here, wrt the transition.